# Android StreetView not loading

Tags: android, maps

I am getting this error when I am using `StreetView` in my app.
Everything is fine except the map is not loading its just a black screen in the fragment.

> E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader"

Comment: Make sure the authorization passes right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.
Your view is going out side of the screen. In the main Layout probably you forget to give orientation. Please follow this type of layout. Here in the main LinearLayout I give the orientation so now Mapview is coming in the screen. It will solve your problem.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical"
> android:layout_height="match_parent">
> <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
> <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
>     android:id="@+id/map"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```